# Identify faucet manufacturer

Tags: faucet, outdoor, frost

I have a faucet leaking from the anti syphon on the top. I need to replace the parts but don’t know the manufacturer. The original cap is long gone. It only has asse 1018 on the side. There are no other markings. Please help.

[image]

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Woodford-17-Metal-Handle-Repair-Kit-10-Piece-RK-17MH/202527188.  Have a look at this kit it may do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Nibco 90. https://duckduckgo.com/?q=nibco+90+hydrant&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images  ...........